# To run a linux and SQL command in python

Tags: python

Can someone help me to execute the below line of code in python?

```
cat /home/dbadmin/super_app/data/file_name.spool | vsql database -U user -w 'password' -c "copy schema.table from stdin direct no escape null as '\N'"
```

Comment: Hint: `subprocess`, `shell=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `subprocess` library has support for pipes. The following code is simply the [documentation example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) modified a bit:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(["cat", "/home/dbadmin/super_app/data/file_name.spool"],
           stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["vsql", "database", "-U", "user", "-w", "password",
            "-c", "copy schema.table from stdin direct no escape null as '\\N'"],
           stdin=p1.stdout,
           stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

I haven't tested the above code, so there might be some typos.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect job for Python's excellent `subprocess` library. You can run shell commands like so:

```
subprocess.call("YOURCOMMANDHERE", shell=True)
```

This will return a `returncode` so you know if the command completed succesfully. If you need output from the command, you can use a different subprocess function:

```
 subprocess.check_output("YOURCOMMANDHERE")
```

Which will return the commands output as a string. Read more about this library [in the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)